# Parse data from one column into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database, ssms, delimiter, ansi-sql

I have a field `[Field_Attributes_Value]` I need to parse into 11 different columns based on `'|'` as the deliminiter and each value between `'|'` gets placed into the below fields. Example of value to be parsed into 11 columns: `'Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value | Value'`.

However the data is not splitting but rather populating all into Field 1

````
SELECT Input_Type_ID, [Field_Attributes_Value] as Input, Input_Type,
   REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 1)) AS [Field 1]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 2)) AS [Field 2]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 3)) AS [Field 3]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 4)) AS [Field 4]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 5)) AS [Field 5]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 6)) AS [Field 6]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 7)) AS [Field 7]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 8)) AS [Field 8]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 9)) AS [Field 9]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 10)) AS [Field 10]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Field_Attributes_Value]), ' | ', ' '), 11)) AS [Field 11]
   
     FROM [dbo].[Taxonomy_Fields]```
````

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve].

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem. I can at least tell you that PARSENAME cannot handle more that 4 objects; So if your string has more than 3 `.` then the function always returns NULL for all indexes :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using REVERSE here, but when i understand you correct than i think you need to split your string. So depending on your dbms you are using you can try something like this.

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX([Field_Attributes_Value], '|', 1),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX([Field_Attributes_Value], '|', 0)) + 1),
       '|', '') AS AS [Field 1]

REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX([Field_Attributes_Value], '|', 2),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX([Field_Attributes_Value], '|', 1)) + 1),
       '|', '') AS AS [Field 2]
```

Comment: thank you but it says SUBSTRING_INDEX is not a recognized built-in function. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, if i'm right you are working with MSSQL. Can you try to use STRING_SPLIT function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15